# Can't load stylesheet on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, stylesheet, media

I am using a single stylesheet for both mobile and desktop and utilizing `@media all`.  The queries work on the desktop, but the stylesheet will not load at all on mobile.  I have tried iOS and Android.  I am also using the tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

and

```
<link href="http://localhost/Atoz/css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  media="all"/><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

here is my

Comment: <sarcasm>Oh well. If you've tried 'everything' and it still doesn't work, then clearly it doesn't and cant. </sarcasm> What did the forums _you already searched_ turn up in terms of answers? Do none of the solutions/work-arounds work?

Comment: You gotta provide more info or @enhzflep wins.

Comment: Can you post the full <head> contents?

Comment: Try my answer whether its working or not for you !

Comment: let me know your feedback once you tried

Comment: @enhzflep I have yet to find one that does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css" />
```

Mobile Related jQuery Plugins are below. it will make your life easy.

http://jquerymobile.com/
http://jqtjs.com/
[http://phonegap.com/](http://phonegap.com/one)

Comment: I finally got it! Thanks a lot! I had to link to my stylesheets without the "http://localhost/Atoz". I also add your code thank you!